# if gradient is passed then gradient or color in box decoration

Tags: flutter, dart, colors, linear-gradients

```
  InkWell buildAppBarActionItem({
     Gradient gradient,
    String icon,
    double width = 36,
    double height = 36,
    double radius = 12,
  
    Color color,
    Function onpressed,
    double opacity = 1,
  }) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onpressed,
      child: Container(
        width: width,
        height: height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(radius),
          ),
          **if(color){
            color: color.withOpacity(opacity)
           }
          else{
          gradient: StyleBtn.buildLinearGradient(begin: Alignment.topLeft, eng: Alignment.topRight)
             }**

          // color? color: color.withOpacity(opacity) : gradient: StyleBtn.buildLinearGradient(begin: Alignment.topLeft, eng: Alignment.topRight),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: ImageIcon(
            AssetImage("assets/icon/${icon}"),
            size: 16.0,
            color: MyTheme.white,
          ),
        ),
     
      ),
    );
  }
```

i want to show gradient if gradient is passed to the function or if color is passed color is shown. i have implemented this, but it's expecting an identifier. don't know how to put this and where to

Comment: simply use both: `color: effectiveColor, gradient: effectiveGradient` - note that both `color` and `gradient` accepts nulls so if `effectiveColor` is `null` it is simply not used

Comment: don't understand what's your point...
my problem is in ** if to else**

Comment: my point is to pass both `color: ...` and `gradient: ...` to `BoxDecoration`

Comment: no it doesn't work that way

Comment: color and gradient at the same time

Comment: both `color` and `gradient` can be `null` and in that case nulls are ignored by those two properties, in the answer below made by @eamirho3ein you can see how it works

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
InkWell buildAppBarActionItem({
     Gradient? gradient,
    String? icon,
    double width = 36,
    double height = 36,
    double radius = 12,
  
    Color? color,
    Function()? onpressed,
    double opacity = 1,
  }) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onpressed,
      child: Container(
        width: width,
        height: height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(radius),
          ),
          color: color != null? color.withOpacity(opacity) : null,
          gradient: color == null? StyleBtn.buildLinearGradient(begin: Alignment.topLeft, eng: Alignment.topRight) : null,
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: ImageIcon(
            AssetImage("assets/icon/${icon}"),
            size: 16.0,
            color: MyTheme.white,
          ),
        ),
     
      ),
    );
  }
```

In non-nullable app do this:

```
InkWell buildAppBarActionItem({
     Gradient gradient,
    String icon,
    double width = 36,
    double height = 36,
    double radius = 12,
  
    Color color,
    Function() onpressed,
    double opacity = 1,
  }) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onpressed,
      child: Container(
        width: width,
        height: height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(radius),
          ),
          color: color != null? color.withOpacity(opacity) : null,
          gradient: color == null? StyleBtn.buildLinearGradient(begin: Alignment.topLeft, eng: Alignment.topRight) : null,
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: ImageIcon(
            AssetImage("assets/icon/${icon}"),
            size: 16.0,
            color: MyTheme.white,
          ),
        ),
     
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: building the project  without nullable feature. it throughs me  "Unimplemented handling of missing static target". can you tell me how to handle this. TIA

Comment: still it has the same error

Comment: stop project, close you ide then open and start it again.

Comment: glad to hear that, if it helps you please approve it so other people find it easier in future.